# Check multi-value duplication in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Inputs**

I have a Dataframe with several columns.

```
proof_path = 

   #1  X  Y  #2 X_  Z  #3  W Z_  #4 W_ Y_
0  p1  a  b  p2  a  c  p2  a  c  p3  a  b
1  p1  a  b  p2  a  c  p3  a  c  p1  a  b
2  p1  a  b  p2  a  d  p3  e  d  p4  e  b
```

In the above Dataframe, I want to examine whether each row is duplicated between `[#1, X, Y]`, `[#2, X_, Z]`, `[#3, W, Z_]`, and `[#4, W_, Y_]`.

For example, in rows corresponding to index 0, `[#2, X_, Z]` and `[#3, W_, Z_]` overlap with `[P2, a, c]`.
In addition, `[#1, X, Y]` and `[#4, W_, Y_]` in row corresponding to index 1 overlap `[P1, a, b]`. I'm going to drop rows that overlap between these multi-values from that dataframe.

My desired output is

**output**

```
proof_path = 

   #1  X  Y  #2 X_  Z  #3  W Z_  #4 W_ Y_
2  p1  a  b  p2  a  d  p3  e  d  p4  e  b
```

And i tried as follows.

```
triple_size = 3
for depth in range(int(len(proof_path.columns)/triple_size)-1):
    for i in range(1, int(len(proof_path.columns)/triple_size)-depth):
        current_rComp = proof_path.iloc[:, depth*size:(depth+1)*triple_size]
        next_rComp = proof_path.iloc[:, (depth+i)*size:(depth+i+1)*triple_size]
        current_rComp.columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj']
        next_rComp.columns = ['pred', 'subj', 'obj']
        proof_path = proof_path[current_rComp.ne(next_rComp).any(axis=1)]
```

Although these methods were able to achieve desired results, they are inefficient by generating sub set of `proof_path` for each iteration. Is there a simple way to accomplish these tasks?

Comment: Would it make things easier if you had read the dataframe into only four columns in the first place? e.g. `#1, X, Y` is the first column `#2, X_, Z` the second etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the nested loops, you could use sets: For each row, put the four triples of values in a set. The number of elements in the set is the number of unique triples. Then you can use this number of unique triples as a mask to select rows:

```py
import numpy as np

proof_path['n_unique_triples'] = \
    proof_path.apply(lambda row: len(set((tuple(row[0:3]),
                                          tuple(row[3:6]),
                                          tuple(row[6:9]),
                                          tuple(row[9:12])))), axis=1)
    
df_select = proof_path[proof_path.n_unique_triples == 4]
df_select
```

```
    #1  X   Y   #2  X_  Z   #3  W   Z_  #4  W_  Y_  n_unique_triples
2   p1  a   b   p2  a   d   p3  e   d   p4  e   b   4
```